# java generics reflection: get Class<T> from generic returns TypeVariableImpl instead of

Tags: java, reflection

This is my code, shared [here](https://www.online-java.com/X0aDikWobq), so you can run it.

```java
public interface GenericRepository<T> {
    default Class<T> getEntityClazz() {
        ParameterizedType pType = (ParameterizedType)this.getClass().getGenericInterfaces()[0];
        Type tT = pType.getActualTypeArguments()[0];
        Class<T> clazz = (Class<T>) tT.getClass();
        
        return clazz;
    }
}
```

```java
public class GenericRepositoryImpl<T> implements GenericRepository<T> {
    
}
```

My main is:

```java
public class Main
{
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        GenericRepository<Example> genericObject = new GenericRepositoryImpl();
        Class<Example> clazz = genericObject.getEntityClazz();
        System.out.println("Generic class: " + clazz.toString());
    }
}
```

And output is:

> Generic class: class sun.reflect.generics.reflectiveObjects.TypeVariableImpl

I was expecting to get `Generic class: class Example`.

Any ideas?

Comment: But you have `implements GenericRepository<T>`, not `implements GenericRepository<Example>`. So, you're grabbing the `T`, and that's a `TypeVariable`, as expected.

Comment: Perhaps you wanted the non-generic `public class GenericRepositoryImpl implements GenericRepository<Example> { ... }`. That will also fix the raw type problem you have in `main`.

Comment: Or just drop the `GenericRepositoryImpl` class and use `GenericRepository<Example> genericObject = newGenericRepository<Example>(){};` Since Java 9 you can even use type inference: `GenericRepository<Example> genericObject = new GenericRepository<>() {};` But it should also be noted that you have to return the actual type, i.e. `tT`, not `tT.getClass()`.

Answer (score 3):

When you use `this.getClass()`, you're basically dealing with the definition of the class, not the INSTANCE which holds the generic information you may need.
If you declaring you generic type like `A<T extends B>`, then you can retrieve the type of `B` by using `((TypeVariableImpl)pType.getActualTypeArguments()[0]).getBounds()[0]`, but I don't think that's what you want to do.

So I would suggest 2 other alternatives:

1, Just return the class type in your implementation class, in with the generic type is explicitly specified:

```
public class GenericRepositoryImpl implements GenericRepository<Example> {
@Override
public Class<Example> getEntityClazz() {
    return Example.class;
    }
}
```

2, When you still want to get the type of generic type in the generic class itself, then save it somewhere when you initialize the object, the trade-off is that you have to put that type in as an argument to initialize:

```
public class GenericRepositoryImpl<T> implements GenericRepository<T> {
private final Class<T> type;

public GenericRepositoryImpl(Class<T> type) {
    this.type = type;
}

@Override
public Class<T> getEntityClazz() {
    return this.type;
    }
}
```

And the usage would be like this :

```
public class Main {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    GenericRepository<Example> genericObject = new GenericRepositoryImpl(Example.class);
    System.out.println("Generic class: " + genericObject.getEntityClazz().toString());
    }
}
```

Comment: Though just to note, having `implements GenericRepository<Example>` _should_ result in the  OP's default implementation of `getEntityClass()` returning `Class<Example>`.

Answer (score 2):

In Java you deal with generic type erasure, so...

```
public interface GenericRepository<T> {
    Class<T> getEntityClazz();
}

//declared as abstract so override of getEntityClazz() is not required here
public abstract class GenericRepositoryImpl<T> implements GenericRepository<T> {
    //common fields and logic
}

public class ExampleReposirory extends GenericRepositoryImpl<Example> {
    //constructor calling super
    @Override
    public Class<T> getEntityClazz() {
        return Example.class;
    }
}
```

This approach is rather verbose, but at least wins in clarity and straightforwardness compared to the magic of reflection